# Workspace stays fixed on external monitor when switching workspace

Tags: multiple-monitors, gnome, workspaces

Im using ubuntu 11.10, running, and loving, the gnome3 interface.

I am running an optimus enabled laptop with bumblebee.

i just figured out how to put the top panel on my external monitor (connected via VGA), which therefore makes my external my 'primary' monitor (a.k.a thats where all the action happens). However now i notice that when i switch workspaces, only the external monitor switches, my laptop screen remains in a fixed workspace.

It should be noted that if move the top panel back to my laptop screen, the problem reverses in that the workspace on my external monitor remains fixed when switching workspaces, i just didn't notice this before.

Is there any way to get my laptop screen to switch as well?

Thank you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This behaviour is by design. The GNOME designers decided this was the best thing to do, not taking their actual users into account.

[image]

Luckily the behaviour can be reverted. You can use Gnome Tweaks or execute the following in the terminal, re-login and you're all set:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.overrides workspaces-only-on-primary false
```

or using this on older systems:

```
gconftool-2 --set /desktop/gnome/shell/windows/workspaces_only_on_primary false --type bool
```

You probably want to have panels and workspace preview on all monitors too: [How to have both monitors in the workspace preview for Gnome Shell?](https://askubuntu.com/q/632132)

Answer (score 1):

I just found this:

https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2732/workspaces-seem-to-only-apply-to-the-primary-display-is-this-a-feature-or-a-bug

It seems that workspaces-only-on-primary is here for me:

**org / gnome / mutter / workspaces-only-on-primary**

Comment: On gnome version 3.34.1: I needed to do this. Just switching the one under `gnome/shell` didn't do anything.