# How to have both monitors in the workspace preview for Gnome Shell?

Tags: 14.04, gnome, multiple-monitors, workspaces

For my Gnome Shell, I have disabled that Workspaces should be on primary display only. So now, whenever I switch the workspace, both monitors switch their content as they should.

Yet when I press <kbd>Meta</kbd> in order to get a preview of my Workspaces, all I see is the preview of the workspace's content of the primary monitor.

This makes navigating my worksapces pretty hard as I have to know on which secondary monitor some window is hiding.

How do I get a prewiew of all monitors' content in the preview?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is doable with an extension called [multi-monitors-add-on](https://github.com/spin83/multi-monitors-add-on).

You can also find it on [extensions.gnome.org](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/921/multi-monitors-add-on/) for installation.

If you are using the latest version of Gnome shell (3.14 and 3.16) use the master branch:

```
git clone git://github.com/spin83/multi-monitors-add-on.git
cd multi-monitors-add-on
cp -r multi-monitors-add-on@spin83 ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
```

For Ubuntu 14.04, which has Gnome shell 3.10, use the `gnome-3-10` branch:

```
git clone git://github.com/spin83/multi-monitors-add-on.git
git checkout gnome-3-10
cd multi-monitors-add-on
cp -r multi-monitors-add-on@spin83 ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
```

then restart gnome shell and enable the extension. To enable it, you can use the Tweak Tool.

The result:

[image: Screenshot of multi monitor preview of workspaces]

The extension has a lot of options including removing panels and such. I turn off the panel on the extra monitors and then leave "Thumbnails-Slider" options turned on.

Comment: Could you please make it more clear of how to enable the extension?

Comment: Within Gnome tweak tools, I see the extension but cannot enable it ("Does not support shell version"). Searching for the extension on the [extension.gnome.org](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/921/multi-monitors-add-on/) shows it as outdated. Is this really for Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: @k0pernikus, I've just installed the extension in Fedora 24, GNOME Shell 3.20.4, so I believe it should work fine in Ubuntu 14.04 or even 16.04.